# css won't load after jquery ajax call in partial view

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm trying to change the content of the menu whenever the user clicks a button.  The CSS loads fine initially, but once i press the button to initiate the ajax call, the menu bar returns, but none of the CSS is applied. All of the code is in an MVC 4 partial view.

[image: Before I hit the button]

[image: After I hit the button]

Here's my JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#menu").wijmenu({
        orientation: 'vertical'
    });

    $("#TDButtons a").click(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        $('#menuAjax').fadeOut('slow', LoadAjaxContent(href));
        return false;
    });

    function LoadAjaxContent(href) {

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: href,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#menuAjax").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });

    }
});
```

Here's the nav tag

```
   <nav id="menuAjax">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Breaking News</a>
                <ul>
                  ...
```

Here's the HTML for the buttons to initiate the AJAX

```
   <div class="navDiv">
        <div id="TDButtons">
            <a href="@Url.Action("_menu", "Home", new { TakeoutDelivery = "TakeOut" }, null)">
                <img class="headerLogo" src="../../Content/Images/TakeoutButton.jpg" alt="Take Out" /></a>
            <a href="@Url.Action("_menu", "Home", new { TakeoutDelivery = "Delivery" }, null)">
                <img class="headerLogo" src="../../Content/Images/DeliveryButton.jpg" alt="Delivery" /></a>
        </div>
```

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add

```
$("#menu").wijmenu({
    orientation: 'vertical'
});
```

into the LoadAjaxContent function.

```
function LoadAjaxContent(href) {
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#menuAjax").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
            $("#menu").wijmenu({
                orientation: 'vertical'
            });
        }
    });
}​
```

Answer (score 3):

Put this on the page.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
 $('#OutsideDiv').trigger('create');
}
```

This will re attach the css on page load. The problem I presume is that it is only a partial post and hence you are lossing the style sheets. I had a very similar problem with my mobile site in jquery-mobile when making partial postback calls. This fixed it re partial postbacks.....

Note: there is a very small delay for it to render... Not sure if this will be a problem for you....

Hope it helps

Cheers
Robin